# What is the Typescript type to accept any kind of React Component as prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that can accept another component as a prop.

Very simplified example:

```
interface Props {
  Comp: React.ComponentClass<unknown> | React.SFC<unknown>
}

const MyComp: React.FC<props> = ({ Comp }) => {
  return React.createElement(Comp)
}
```

What would be the most simple type for Comp that accepts functional components, class based components, etc?

The type definition of createElement makes it look rather complicated
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L286

Comment: `React.ComponentType`?

Comment: `React.ReactNode`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### React.ComponentType

[`React.ComponentType<P>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d1530f63fd7bccb471b5112d16f8873f9fd22079/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L86) is the type for either a class component (`React.ComponentClass<P>`) or function component (`React.FunctionComponent<P>` aka `React.FC<P>`) which takes props `P`.

(FYI, `React.ReactNode` and `React.ReactElement` are the types for the JSX returned by the component - not for a callable component)

#### Typing Comp's Props

You do not want to use `<unknown>` in your `Props` type.  You want to declare that the component requires only the props which you are providing when you call `React.createElement(Comp)` (you call also use JSX and `return <Comp/>`).  In this case you are providing no props, so it would be `React.ComponentType<{}>` or just `React.ComponentType` since `{}` is the default for `P`.

```
interface Props {
  Comp: React.ComponentType;
}

const MyComp: React.FC<Props> = ({ Comp }) => {
  return <Comp />
}
```

with some props:

```
interface Props {
  Comp: React.ComponentType<{someKey: string}>;
}

const MyComp: React.FC<Props> = ({ Comp }) => {
  return <Comp someKey="someValue" />
}
```

You will get an error if you call `Comp` without providing `someKey`, which is good!  You don't get that error when calling `React.createElement(Comp)` because for some reason the `props` argument is optional.  So in my opinion the JSX approach is better.

Comment: Thanks, this clears this up nicely! I'm not sure why this was so hard to find out. I've bee using `unknown` because of this warning: "Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value"."

Comment: Also one more point: ComponentType doesn't seem to accept  `keyof ReactHTML` which is not a problem in my case because i'm using react native, but would be nice to have.

Answer (score -1):

What I use and see in many projects is this:

```
interface ComponentProps {
    myComponentAsProp: () => React.ReactNode
}

const HomePage: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{props.myComponentAsProp()}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

To render it is like a function call.

Answer (score -4):

It can be so simple. Check this code:

```
import { type ReactNode } from 'react';

interface IProps {
  children?: ReactNode;
}
const HomePage = ({ children }: IProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is Home Page</h1>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```