# What TypeScript type should be used when checking if component is React class or function component?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this JavaScript function:

```
export const isClassComponent = component => {
  return (
    typeof component === 'function' &&
    Boolean(component.prototype.isReactComponent)
  );
};
```

The purpose of the function is to check if a passed in object (`component`) is a React function component. The approach is based on [this overreacted guide](https://overreacted.io/how-does-react-tell-a-class-from-a-function/). There are no other requirements for the function besides confirming or rejecting that the `component` is a React function component.

To convert that function to a TypeScript function, it is necessary to add a type to `component`, which can be *any* JS value or object (not just a React [`ComponentType`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L105)). What type should be added to achieve the desired functionality?

I tried the below, but not sure it makes sense.

```
type ComponentType<P, R> = (p: P) => R;
export const isClassComponent = <P, R>(component: ComponentType<P, R>) => {
  return (
    typeof component === 'function' &&
    Boolean(component.prototype.isReactComponent)
  );
};
```

Also `component.prototype` becomes of type `any`, which should be avoided - the TypeScript ESLint rules complain about the `component.prototype`: `Unsafe member access .isReactComponent on an 'any' value.`. It should probably be of type `Record<string, unknow>`, just with `unknown` replaced (not sure by what).

Comment: What range of inputs do you want to support? Is it to find out if `any`thing is a React class component, or just something you already know's a [`ComponentType`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5dddaaa384aaba8ba23840fb8132f2f9f800c9ef/types/react/index.d.ts#L93-L105)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Typescript type to accept any kind of React Component as prop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66412660/what-is-the-typescript-type-to-accept-any-kind-of-react-component-as-prop)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for checking. The function should support passing in any object or value. It could be a string, a plain function, or otherwise. Based on that input parameter (`component`), it should confirm whether whatever was passed in is a function component.

Comment: I'd start with `unknown`, then.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you have time, could you please write out the function in an answer, also showing how it is called? I have read up on `unknown `, but unsure how it would be used here.

Comment: `(component: unknown)`?! Read the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown

Comment: @jonrsharpe I read up on it, but here are some points that are still unclear to me: 1) Do I need to cast (assert) type when calling function where prop is of `unknown` type? 2) Is using generics not better, to allow caller to decide type? 3) The post you linked says `You do not want to use <unknown> in your Props type`, is that pattern advised against?

Comment: @jonrsharpe ... and 4) How should the `any` issue with the prototype be tackled?

Comment: Without more context on the intended _usage_, it's unclear what you need. Do you need to maintain generics? Perhaps. Should it be an actual [_type predicate_](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) instead of the inferred `boolean`? Maybe. Hence I said I'd _start_ with `unknown`, but you may find you need to enrich that. I certainly don't know why you think the prototype being `any` should or even could be avoided. And you seem to be confusing props specifically with arguments to a function generally - this function _isn't_ itself a component.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Re. 4: The official ESLint rules from typescript complains about the prototype access: `Unsafe member access .isReactComponent on an 'any' value.` Re. the other points, the function should just do what I described, i.e. confirm whether the passed in object or literal is a React function component. I do not need the return type to be of any type other than boolean.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-is?

Comment: @JakubKotrs No I hadn't, that's pretty cool. Thanks. I try to stay clear of superfluous third-party dependencies, but might use this in the future.